# Sort by character count, replacing strings

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list that looks like

> ### Col A
>
> 1. FU010402350000
> 2. FU0366090000
> 3. FU0023750000
> 4. FU010587090000
> 5. FU0368420000
> 6. FU010671340000

Everyday it needs sorting, the character count for a real string value is 14 characters, so the ones that are 14 characters are correct, but the 12 character strings need editing to become 'real'.

The thing is, it needs to have 00 at the beginning, after FU.

My train of thought is

> If < 12 characters add 00 after FU, otherwise if it's 14 characters ignore cell

## How can I set up a macro to filter by character count, replace values if it isn't < 12?

Here is my start

`Sub charactercountfilter()`

```
' Get rownumber of lastrow of data Col A
lastrow = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

' Check row 1 to last row #, Col A
For i = 1 To lastrow
    ' If less than 12 chars
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 12 Then
        ' ...
Next i
```

`End Sub`

Comment: `=Left(A1,2) & TEXT(--MID(A1,3,12),"000000000000")`

Comment: I receive a #VALUE! error when trying this.

Comment: Do you have different values than what you provided.  Currently you have all numbers after the first 2 characters.  do you have others where there are alpha characters after the first two?

Comment: Your comment below shed some light on what I was doing wrong. Thank you Scott.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be quicker as it works with a variant array and only accesses the worksheet twice:

```
Sub FU0014character()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet12") 'Change to your sheet or ActiveSheet

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Dim arr As Variant
arr = rng.Value

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    arr(i, 1) = Left$(arr(i, 1), 2) & Format(Val(Mid$(arr(i, 1), 3)), "000000000000")
Next i

rng.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: So much faster, thank you for helping me with the solution! During my search of trying to do this I saw this method being used, but I had issues with it because it changed the leading values with 0's. This seems to skip the letters by skipping the first two characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FU0014character()
'
' selectbinsertcolumn Macro
'
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' Get rownumber of lastrow of data Col A
lastrow = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

' Check row 1 to last row #, Col A
For i = 1 To lastrow
    ' If less than 14 chars
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 14 Then
        ' Take data and apply it to right column
        Cells(i, 1) = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).FillRight

    End If
    ' Not less than 14 - get next row
Next i


Columns("B").Replace What:="FU", _
                        Replacement:="FU00", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

For i = 1 To lastrow
    ' If longer than 12 chars
    If Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 12 Then
        ' move to right
        Cells(i, 1) = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).FillRight

    End If
    ' Not less than 12 - get next row
Next i


Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Basically what this does is, creates a new column (new column b) it then checks if Column A values character count is 14 characters, if it is less than 14 it will move it to the right, in the new column B.

Then it replaces every (12 character) in column B's FU with FU00.

It runs the column A check again, this time looking if it's greater than 12 and if they are (obviously, because they would've been moved at the first check), it will move it to the right in column B.

It then deletes the blank Column A.